# Run Exploitable Applications As Nobody?

Tags: permissions, firefox, sudo, security, chromium

I would like to know if it is possible, and if so how, to run *exploitable* applications, such as web browsers because of malicious Javascript on websites, as **nobody** user even though my actual user is a administrator/sudoer? I'm asking this question because I don't want to have my data compromised because of the fact that a privileged user is running applications such as chromium or firefox.

Comment: I think you want a VPN (Virtual Private Network) although I've never used one and cannot assist.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks for your respond. I'm not fully sure to understand how a VPN can solve this problem. To my knowledge, a browser, for example, can still execute a malicious code of a website on user's system, with or without VPN.

Comment: It's easier to use a Snap version of the browser - built-in confinement.

Comment: @user535733  Oh! I didn't know about that. I'll look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't work well with user *nobody*, because this account does not have a home directory to write into.

But given you have a normal user called *otheruser*, a very simple way to run a graphical application as another user is to use ssh X11 forwarding. For example with firefox, just do this

```
ssh -X otheruser@localhost firefox
```

and you should have a new browser instance running as user *otheruser*, but usable through your normal users GUI.

Obviously this approach needs sshd running, so in case you haven't installed it, run `sudo apt install openssh-server` first. If you are worried about adding a network daemon to your system you can configure sshd such that it will only listen to the localhost network interface, which is enough for above solution to work.